# Add Columns Properties in JQGrid from array

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I have an array which contains following elements.

```
var column = { };
column["name"] = "Id";
column["sorttype"] = 'int';
column["hidden"] = true;
column["editable"] = false;
arr1.push(column);

column["name"] = "Name";
column["sorttype"] = 'string';
column["hidden"] = false;
column["editable"] = true;
arr1.push(column);

column["name"] = "Age";
column["sorttype"] = 'int';
column["hidden"] = false;
column["editable"] = true;
arr1.push(column);

column["name"] = "Address";
column["sorttype"] = 'string';
column["hidden"] = false;
column["editable"] = true;
arr1.push(column);
```

Also have a jqgrid. Which use the columns exactly same as arr1

```
$("#grid").jqGrid({ //set your grid id
    datatype: "local",
    colNames: s,
    colModel: [{
        name: 'id',
        index: 'id',
        sorttype: 'int',
        hidden:true ,
        editable: false,
    }, {
        name: 'Name',
        index: 'Name',
        editable: false?, 
    }, {
        name: 'Age',
        index: 'Age',
        editable: true,
    }, {
        name : 'Address',index :'Address'
        sortable:true,
        editable:true,
    },
});
```

I want to replace the colModel from Jqgrid by arr1. Is it possible please help

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you just have to replace the colModel array with arr1

```
$("#grid").jqGrid({ //set your grid id
    datatype: "local",
    colNames: s,
    colModel: arr1
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I add column["index"] and push to arr1
then replace the code by 
    $("#grid").jqGrid({ //set your grid id
        datatype: "local",
        colNames: s,
        colModel: arr1
    });

It is worked

Comment: Adding of `column["index"]` is not needed. The answer of Kiran Reddy provides the code which you need already. By the way you should verify whether `editable: false?,` exists really in your code or it's a typing error. It should be `editable: false,` or better you can remove the property because the value `editable: false` is default. You should verify whether you need to have `Name` editable or not. It's not editable in the original code and it's editable in `arr1`.

Comment: Sorry It is not worked I have an error length of column name <> colModel

Comment: The error means that `s` array which you use as `colNames` have not the same size as `arr1`. One more typical error which makes some users is the usage of **strings** instead of objects. You can include `alert("typeof s = " + typeof s);alert("typeof arr1 = " + typeof arr1);`. If you will see `string` at least one then you made an error. By the way you can don't use `colNames` at all. Instead of that you can set `label` property for items of `colModel` with the same value which you use for `colNames` items.